# how to separate the response div ids in ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Please help me out to resolve the issue.

```
function createRequestObject(){
    var req;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
    //For Firefox, Safari, Opera
    req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if(window.ActiveXObject){
    //For IE 5+
    req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    else{
    //Error for an old browser
    }
    return req;
}

var http = createRequestObject();

function empajax(method,nameId)
{
   url='college/cat/employee.jsp'+"?nameId="+nameId;
   if(method == 'POST'){
        http.open(method,url,true);
        http.onreadystatechange = handleResponse;
        http.send(null);
    }   
}

function handleResponse(){
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200){
        var response = http.responseText;
        if(response){
            $("#empname").html(response);
            $("#empnumber").html(response);
          }
    }      
}
```

In the above ajax function, employee.jsp is returing below values in below divs. How to separate the div responses in the habdleResponse() function to set the values in corresponding divs like (empname,empnumber)

```
<div> 
    <b>ram</b> 
</div>

<div> 
    <b>1234</b> 
</div>
```

I just wan to set the employee name in the empname div and employee number in the empnumber div.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the information you are trying to extract in a xml document?

Comment: what you are getting in response?

Comment: In the response i am getting below value <div> 
    <b>ram</b> 
</div>

<div> 
    <b>1234</b> 
</div>

Comment: Try making your document with these values (given it is XML):

 <empname> ram </empname>
 <empnum> 1234 </empnum>

Comment: url='college/cat/employee.jsp  this url returning 2 div values in the same response. i want to separate empname and empnumber in diffrent id. is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to traverse your XML dom:

```
function handleResponse(){
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200){
     var xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML;
      root = xmlResponse.documentElement;
      names = root.getElementsByTagName("empname");
      numbs = root.getElementsByTagName("empnum");

     for (var i = 0 ; i < numbs.length; i++)  {
     throw(names[i].firstChild.data, numbs[i].firstChild.data);


}
```

Then just pass over the variables to a function that will throw them in the document:

```
 function throw(name , number) {

var divider = document.createElement('div') ;
divider.innerHTML = "<div class='name'>" + name + " </div> <div class='numb'>" + number +"</div>"
 document.appendChild(divider);  

}
```

And then you'll have it. A separate div for each of your entry.

Comment: Hi hristo georgiev, I am trying to extract the information from the jsp. (url='college/cat/employee.jsp).

Comment: I can't see what's in the .jsp file. Can you upload it somewhere? It's more important to see what kind of data it passes. It can be either JSON or XML.

Comment: <dsp:page>
 <div>
  <b>xxxxxxx</b>
 </div>
 <div>
  <b>12345</b>
 </div>
</dsp:page>

Comment: above is the content in the .jsp... Also in the alert i am getting the div values as i mentioned.

Comment: Try changing it to:
<dsp:page [xml="{true}"]> <empname> xxxxx </empname> <empnum> 1234 </empnum> </dsp:page>

And use my code above.